# Spring: correctly show error messages with HTML entities

Tags: spring-mvc, html-entities

In my controller, I have the following:

```
errors.rejectValue("product", "errors.invalid", new Object[]{
    new DefaultMessageSourceResolvable(new String[]{"label.error.message"})}, "");
```

In the properties file, there is the following:

```
errors.invalid={0} is invalid.
label.error.message=Product&reg;
```

In the JSP page, I have:

```
<form:errors path="product" cssClass="field-error"/>
```

Where there is an input error, I now get this message:

```
Product&reg; is invalid.
```

What I hope to achieve is to show the following:

Product® is invalid.

Thanks!

Comment: what if you put Product® in properties file?

Comment: ACV, I thought about your solution before posting the question. I did what you said, and it works. I was hoping to use some kind of html escape Spring provides, and I believe Spring has such a mechanism for this job, but dont know how to do it. I will wait tow days to choose yours as the answer if I cannot get it done in the next two days. Throughout my properties file, I have been consistently using html entities. Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straight from [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#spring-form.tld.errors)

> htmlEscape - Enable/disable HTML escaping of rendered values.

Comment: thanks for chiming in! I already saw that. My problem is I cannot figure out how to apply html escape in this case. Thanks, again.

Comment: `<form:errors path="product" cssClass="field-error" htmlEscape="false"/>`